# Merge objects without loosing data in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, optimization, data-loss

Facing optimization issue with merging two objects which can have the same keys.

A solution without using any loops is desired, or some algorithm to make this efficient.

**Problem**

There are two objects, one **Parent** and the other is the **Child**.
The Parent can contain **Child** keys, and **Child** can have new keys.

I want a merged object without losing any data from either **Child** or **Parent**.

The efficiency should be less than `N` which is the number of the **Child** keys.

```
const parent = {
   one: {
    alpha:{}
   },
   two: {},
   three: {},
}

const child = {
   one: {
    beta:{}
   },
   four: {}
}

//result should be
{
   one: {
    alpha:{},
    beta:{}
   },
   two: {},
   three: {},
   four: {}
}
```

As in the above sample, both objects got merged without any loss of data.

**What I have tired?**

A single for_loop on the child compares keys and spreads them(to respective keys) or pushes them to the final array. The efficiency here is N which is the size of the child's keys array.

[Working example to understand the problem](https://replit.com/@RajRohit/RNStylesGenerator)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const parent = {
  one: {
   alpha:{}
  },
  two: {},
  three: {},
}

const child = {
  one: {
   beta:{}
  },
  four: {}
}

// Copy parent object to new variable
const newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parent))

Object.keys(child).forEach((key) => {
  if(!!newObj[key]) {
    newObj[key] = {
      ...newObj[key],
      ...child[key]
    }
  } else {
    newObj[key] = child[key];
  }
})

console.log('parent: ', parent);
console.log('child: ', child);
console.log('New object: ',newObj)
```

Comment: This is not efficient, as I have mentioned. Looking for something efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this. First get an array of strings containing keys of the child object by calling **Object.keys()**. Then iterate over keys array and compare with the parent object. In case parent object has same key then update value of that key with an array containing both parent and child objects values for that key.

```
Object.keys(childObject).forEach((key) => {
   if(parentObject[key]{
      parentObject[key] = [parentObject[key], childObject[key]];
   }else {
      parentObject[key] = childObject[key];
   }
});
```

Comment: This is not efficient, as I have mentioned above. Looking for something efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work to arbitrary depth, you need to write a function that merges each pair of children recursively, like this:

```js
const parent = {
  one: {
   alpha:{}
  },
  two: {},
  three: {},
}

const child = {
  one: {
   beta:{}
  },
  four: {}
}

function merge(a,b) {
   const ret = {...a};
   for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(b)) {
       ret[k] = ret[k] ? merge(ret[k],v) : v;
   }
   return ret;
}
console.log(merge(parent,child));
```